# Is Ownable.sol transferOwnership() an expensive function to run, or am I running it wrong?

Tags: solidity, gas, gas-price

I have a simple ERC20 token, and I would like to transfer the ownership of this contract onto a new address using the Ownable.sol [transferOwnership()](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/access/Ownable.sol) function

When I run this contract, it seems that this function call is going to cost me approximately 1.5 ETH (!!!) if I use a competitive Gas Price (215 GWEI). That seems very expensive considering its my understanding that all that is happening is one variable is being updated on the blockchain.

Am I running something wrong? Here is the etherscan information, I have tried to run it with a very low gas fee but it still seems to cost 0.15ETH (it will probably never be added to a block at this price)

https://etherscan.io/tx/0xb9c184899d8d19e53464509aabd3383508a2320ea67613d3f327a393d8961999

Here is my code:

```
const Web3 = require('web3');
const TestToken= artifacts.require('TestToken.sol');
const web3 = new Web3('https://ropsten.infura.io/v3/<MYKEY>');

module.exports = async function (deployer, network, accounts) {
  const ADMIN_ADDRESS = "...";
  const NEW_ADMIN = "...";


  const TEST_TOKEN= await TestToken.at("...");
  console.log('TEST governance token address: ' + TEST_TOKEN.address);

  const TEST_OWNER = await TEST_TOKEN.owner();
  
  console.log('The owner of the TEST governance token is: ' + TEST_OWNER);
  console.log('Transferring Ownership Now');
  
  let result = await TEST_TOKEN.transferOwnership(NEW_ADMIN);
  const NEW_TEST_OWNER = await TEST_TOKEN.owner();


  console.log('The new owner of the TEST governance token is: ' + NEW_TEST_OWNER);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are right, the `transferOwnership` function only changes the state of a single variable on the contract so it shouldn't require too much gas. The expensive part is that it emits an event, which actually stores data on a block and that is actually expensive.

One possible solution is that you could wait until [EIP-1559](https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/blob/master/EIPS/eip-1559.md) is merged into mainnet which should make gas fees decrease up to 100x, or if you are making your own implementation of the ERC20Token, you could just remove the event emission.